# how to disable clang unused command line argument error in source file

Tags: clang

when I compile a .c file in xcode, there is an error show:

```
clang error: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-objc-exceptions' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

I can append extra command "-Wno-unused-command-line-argument" to the clang command line to disable this warning. But I wonder if it can be disabled in the .c file, so  I add #pragma like these:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-command-line-argument"
...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But it failed.

So, how to disable this warning in the source file exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot suppress this diagnostic by anything you write in your `.c` source
file because the cause of the diagnostic has already been detected and the diagnostic issued
before the `.c` source file is read, as you can observe with this source file:

**fail.c**

```
#error Stop right here
```

and:

```
$ clang -c -fno-objc-exceptions fail.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-objc-exceptions' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
fail.c:1:2: error: Stop right here
#error Stop right here
 ^
1 error generated.
```

The cause of the diagnostic is that `-fno-objc-exceptions` is an option only
applicable to the compilation of Objective C or Objective C++ and clang infers that we are
compiling C, not Objective or Objective C++, just from the fact that the filename `fail.c` has the extension
`.c`, not `.m` or `.mm`